# Can I infer this about probability of drawing a queen or heart from deck of a cards (twice in a row) no replacements?

Tags: probability

So I know the probability of drawing a queen or a heart from a deck of cards is 4/13

Let A be the event a heart or queen is drawn on the first draw

Let B be the event a heart or queen is drawn on the second draw

If I were to draw twice from the deck, with no replacements would, could I assume that

P(A⋂B) + P(A⋂B<sup>C</sup>) = P(A) = 4/13

I found myself making this assumption and was like...wait...can I?

Comment: Well, the probality of doing $A$ will be whatever it is regardless of anything else in the world.  And the events of $B$ and the events of *not* $B$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive so $P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^C)$ had *better* be equal to $P(A \cap (B\cup B^c)) = P(A\cap [anything]) = P(A)$.  If not our development of this mathematical model is not aligned with reality.  .... Now just how this model *does* align with reality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that’s correct, because $A\cap B$ and $A\cap\overline B$ are mutually exclusive, and their union is $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  $P(A$ or $C)= P(A) + P(C) - P(A\cap C)$.

And as $A = A\cup (B\cap B^c) = (A\cap B) \cup (A\cap B^c)$ then

$P(A) = P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B^c) - P([A\cap B] \cap [A\cap B^c])$

But as $B$ and $B^c$ are mutually exclusive $A\cap B$ and $A\cap B^c$ are mutually exclusive so $P([A\cap B] \cap [A\cap B^c]) = 0$.

Basically "the probability of $A$ is the probability of $A$ with something happening plus the probability of $A$ with that something *not* happening" and that really has to be true.